# How to ignore a certain field during search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

suppose I have a MongDB record like below:

{
    name:"name",
    streams: [
        {user:"user0", name:"name0", locked:true},
        {user:"user1", name:"name1", locked:true},
        {user:"user2", name:"name2", locked:false}
    }
}

I want to find all records that have user0 and name0 in the streams field, but I don't care about the locked field

find({streams:{user:"user0", name:"name0"}}) doesn't work, since the locked field is not specified.

Thank You,
Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator which allows you to select the fields from a sub-document in an array that match your conditions:

```js
db.collection.find({ 
    "streams": { "$elemMatch": { "user": "user0", "name": "name0"} }
})
```

Take some time to go through the [Query Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/) in the manual. There are lots of useful operations there.